# Multiple repositories on github

Tags: git, github

I am completely new to GitHub, and I have added two private repositories. One I work on myself, and the second one, we are multiple people working on.

I don't know if I should add multiple SSH-keys, one for each?

I have tried to create two keys, but it seems like it always want to look for the key in /c/Users/{myusername}/.ssh/id_rsa. This means it works fine for the first repository, but not for the second.

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you create a single key pair and use the same public key for multiple repositories.
**This is not a bad thing!**

If you have any reason to use multiple keys you can set it up as described here:
[Multiple SSH Keys](http://help.github.com/multiple-ssh-keys/)

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't get the public ssh-key to work in the first place. It worked when I tried again. Thanks